# Deep Belief Network Sum of the probabilities is not always 1

Tags: deep-learning

I'm using Accord C# library to implement classification with deep belief network.
I set the number of the unit of the last layer(output layer) 2, thus binary classification is implemented. 
What I wonder about is that sum of the probabilities of each classes is not always 1.

As the following:

- [class1]:0.254275667 [class2]:0.304033064    [sum of class1 and class2]:0.558308731
- [class1]:0.527701493 [class2]:0.493994069    [sum of class1 and class2]:1.021695562
- [class1]:0.560147692  [class2]:0.451607344   [sum of class1 and class2]:1.011755035
- [class1]:0.507466963      [class2]:0.366958208   [sum of class1 and class2]:0.874425171

Is it normal? If it is, what does the surplus or shortage mean?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and what makes a good [MCVE]. We cannot reason with this question unless there is something that we can observe and reproduce the problem, in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think probabilities sum depends on type of function you are using. If you use softmax, then you will get the sum 1. otherwise no, I guess